# When is "next times" acceptable?

Tags: grammatical-number

So last night I saw a sentence on the Internet that went like this:

> After you've done it once, it'll be much easier the next times.

Is "the next times" in this example appropriate? If not, are there any other way to phrase it?

P.S. If possible, please let me know whether the present simple tense or the future simple tense is more suitable in this situation.

Thanks for your opinions.

Comment: _The next time_ or _the next few times_ would be much more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

Next times is not used. If you want that concept we would say from now on or in the future. Any more could work in the right context. To make the word "time" plural confuses the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Because there's always only one next time at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The following would be gramatically correct:

> After you've done it once, it will be easier next time.

Notice there is no 'the' before 'next time'. However, if yiu want the definite article you could alternatively write:

> After you've done it once, it will be easier the nect time you do it.